# Animation set with for loop

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I've been trying to find something about this for a while but wasn't able to find what I was looking for. My issue is that I'm just trying to write in a more elegant way a piece of code.

Let's say I have this lines of code:

```
reverse1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
    R.anim.reversefallletter);

reverse2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
    R.anim.reversefallletter);

reverse3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
    R.anim.reversefallletter);

reverse4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
    R.anim.reversefallletter);
```

Is there anyway I can write this with a -for loop- statement, assuming the resource is the same, to look more clearly and more elegant?

Comment: Not if you need it in 4 different variables.

Comment: You could do something like creating an animation list or array and setting them in a loop like that, but then you have to handle things appropriately.

Comment: What can't you use the same variable? As every `reverseX` has the same value...

Comment: @G.T. If the `Animations` are played at the same time you have to use different `Animation` objects. Even if it is the same exact `Animation`.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Oh yes, I didn't think about it. Good to know, thanks

Comment: Exactly! If i use the same variable... At the second touch of the piano key the last animation will start also and so on!

Comment: @BugaIulian If you need different `Animations` for each key, then why do you want to load the same `Animation` four times?

Comment: @XaverKapeller Let's asume I have a fadeIn animation on a letter(a TextView that is invisible till the user presses that key ) that will appear onTouch, if I use the same animation everytime I press the second or the third key the animation will start on each pressed key, and that's why I use different animations!

Comment: @BugaIulian I see, as pretty much everyone already told you, unless you store the `Animations` in some kind of `Collection` there is not much you can do besides using reflection, but I wouldn't consider reflection a more clean or better solution. Both the answers posted here already demonstrate how to load `Animations` into a `Collection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example store the `Animation` objects in an array instead of 4 different variables, then you can do something like this:

```
final Animation[] animations = new Animation[4];
for(int i = 0; i < animations.length; i++) {
    animations[i] = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.reversefallletter);
}
```

Of course you could also use a `List` or some other `Collection`. But if you need it in 4 different variables than there is no other way without using reflection.

---

You could also write a helper method like this:

```
public static Animation[] loadAnimations(Context context, int count, int animationId) {
    final Animation[] animations = new Animation[count];
    for(int i = 0; i < count: i++) {
        animations[i] = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.reversefallletter);
    }
    return animations;
}
```

With it you could save yourself some boilerplate code:

```
Animation[] animations = AnimationHelper.loadAnimations(getActivity(), 4, R.anim.reversefallletter);
```

Comment: That helper method it's something :D

Comment: I thought you might like it. I'm glad I could help!

Comment: By the way! For the performance optimizations what is the better choice for using the code? I mean the "Oldschool way"(as the one from the question) or the "for loop" way?

Comment: It really makes no difference whatsoever. Just know that if you perform many `Animations` at the same time some older devices are going to have trouble keeping up. On the other hand, use arrays whenever possible. A `List` really isn't that expensive on its own, but it does come with some overhead, arrays are always the fastest.

Comment: Tnx a lot for all the tips

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could do it using List or arrays. For instance, using list would be something like :

```
int nbAnimations = 4;
List<Animation> myAnimationsList = new ArrayList<Animation>(nbAnimations);
for (int i = 0; i < nbAnimations; i++) {
    myAnimationsList.add(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.reversefallletter));
}
```

Comment: How is this answer different from mine? Don't post duplicate answer.

Comment: We post the answer at about the same time, i used List you used arrays, dont be that guy please...

Comment: We did not, I was first by more than 4 minutes. If there were something inherently wrong with that I would have down voted your answer, but I'm just saying, don't post duplicate answers, they don't add any value but just more fuzz.

Comment: Our answers are still different, as I said you used Arrays while I used List. Sorry for taking time to wright code correctly and checking that I dod no mistakes (by the way there is a mistake in you for loop > "for(int i = 0; i < animations.length: <<< this is not ":" but ";" <<< i++)"). I'm not rushing to have reputations, be sure about it.